# Pause, resume and restart Canvas animations with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Is there anyway to pause, resume and restart my canvas arc animation progress bar? I've added the click functions in place but no idea where to start in order to achieve what I'm after.

I've added a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4txsqeoh/2/

I would like to make separate functions so can call when needed from the click events etc.

### Update

I've added calls in the click events and empty functions but not sure where to go from here, I'm new to JS.

JS:

```
function init() {
    var c = document.getElementById('draw');
    return c.getContext('2d');
}

function clear(ctx) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
}

function PercentProgress(ctx, percent) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.speed = 4;
    this.x = 100;
    this.y = 100;
    this.radius = 50;

    this.setPercent = function (percent) {
        this.degrees = 360 * (percent / 100);
        this._animationOffset = this.degrees;
        this.percent = percent;
    };

    // Part of initialization
    this.setPercent(percent);

    this.startProgress = function () {
        var self = this;
        clear(this.ctx);
        this._interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.drawProgress();
        }, 10);
    };

    this.pauseProgress = function () {

    };

    this.resumeProgress = function () {

    };

    this.restartProgress = function () {

    };

    this.drawArc = function () {
        var startDegrees = -90;
        var endDegrees = startDegrees + this.degrees - this._animationOffset;
        // Degrees to radians
        var startAngle = startDegrees / 180 * Math.PI;
        var endAngle = endDegrees / 180 * Math.PI;
        // Draw arc
        this.setLineStyles();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        ctx.stroke();
    };

    this.setLineStyles = function () {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF1251';
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    };

    this.drawProgress = function () {
        if (this._animationOffset < 0) {
            this._animationOffset = 0;
        }
        clear(this.ctx);
        this.drawArc();
        this._animationOffset -= this.speed;
        if (this._animationOffset < 0) {
            clearInterval(this._interval);
        }
    };

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    // lets start the progress
    var ctx = init();
    var percentage = 100;
    var progress = new PercentProgress(ctx, percentage);
    //progress.startProgress();

    $(document).on('click', '#pause-progress', function (e) {
        // pause progress
        progress.pauseProgress();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#resume-progress', function (e) {
        // resume progress
        progress.resumeProgress();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#restart-progress', function (e) {
        // restart progress
        progress.startProgress();
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes there is a way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far nothing as a little lost to where to start with it, this has taken me a while alone haha but ive been reading online etc.. and not come across anything yet.

Comment: Hint: To *pause*, you can skip calling `clear(this.ctx);`, `this.drawArc();` and `this._animationOffset -= this.speed;` in `drawAnimation()`. To *stop* you can set `_animationOffset = -1` or clear the interval.

Comment: Ill update code shortly, im just trying to do it with new functions

Comment: Ive updated with a few new bits, calls to funcitons from click events and also added the empty funciton but im new to js and at a stump to how to add them to those funcitons to do what i need them to do :( any help would e massively helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this function

```
    this.setLineStylesCircle = function () {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#001251'; //set the collor here
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    };
```

and change drawArc to this :

```
this.drawArc = function () {

        var startDegrees = -90;
        var endDegrees = startDegrees + this.degrees - this._animationOffset;
        // Degrees to radians
        var startAngle = startDegrees / 180 * Math.PI;
        var endAngle = endDegrees / 180 * Math.PI;
        //Draw circle
        this.setLineStylesCircle();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 7, false);
        ctx.stroke();        
        // Draw arc
        this.setLineStyles();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        ctx.stroke();
    };
```

Comment: Thanks super thanks mate, is there anyway to show it by default as currently just shows once you start the animation? appriciate your efforts and help.

Answer (score 1):

just add this two functions :

```
   this.stop = function(){
            clearInterval(this._interval);
    }

    this.resume = function(){
         var self = this;
         clearInterval(self._interval);
         this._interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.drawAnimation();
        }, 10);
    }
```

and set the click actions like this

```
 $(document).on('click', '#pause-progress', function (e) {
        // pause progress
        anim.stop();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#resume-progress', function (e) {
        // resume progress
          anim.resume();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#restart-progress', function (e) {
        // restart progress
       anim.stop();
       anim = new PercentAnimation(ctx, percentage);
       anim.startAnimation();
    });
```

Comment: Note: `drawAnimation()` should be `drawProgress()` from the OP's edit.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to add a default stroke colour so its a full circle and the progress goes over the top of it?